# How do I solve the knot puzzle?

Tags: broken-age

I'm trying to help F'ther undo the knot, but I'm not getting anywhere. I've sketched out a big state-diagram, but even that hasn't helped - I think I've covered every transition and I still can't find a way to undo the knot. What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find someone who is good at tying knots and ask them for advice.

Hint:

> It's Carol (formerly Car'l) at the beach in Shellmound.

The biggest problem I had with this puzzle was telling this person what the knot looks like then relaying the drawn instructions back to F'ther as spoken dialog (he's a verbal learner).

Comment: Seriously, telling someone that a knot looks like a "bowl full of fingers" and telling F'ther things like "She loves me, she loves me not" as directions?  Hardest puzzle in the game here, I swear.

Comment: I had a knot which 'looked like her' - I thought the first instruction should be 'make the boat go under the bridge' but that failed, and now I have to go all the way back to Shellmound to get another diagram...

Answer (score 1):

I found this really helpful. It has all the knots and drawings: http://www.appunwrapper.com/2015/05/07/broken-age-act-2-walkthrough-guide-untying-the-knots/